# Phpunit prerequisites for windows

Tags: windows, phpunit, twig

I'm new to unit testing, and I wanted to contribute to some projects. So - I forked a repository from git, installed phpunit, executed it, and...  ~200 failures.

The Travis service for exactly identical code returns that build passed.

There aren't any dependencies in composer file, and it's quite baffling. Is it because my environment is Windows (there are a lot of errors about not equal strings, but there aren't any lines marked with --- or +++)?

Comment: Maybe post some the errors to get more information?  It is possible that the test suite for a package has issues, but I would not think so if it is available.  Are you able to run the included tests for PHPUnit without error?

Comment: Are you executing `php` or `phpunit`?

Comment: Well, you should name the repository you cloned so it's more clear what you're speaking about. With the description alone, it's hard to say. With strings this can be character encoding related.

Comment: And I see twig, so probably you have cloned something from symfony2. There are additional prerequisites IIRC.

Comment: @Steven - I've installed phpunit via pear and can't seem to find any included tests. So, I've downloaded it from github (zip, not with git clone), and installed dependencies. It seems that my problem is a little wider than I thought - phpunit self-unittest runs 1038 tests, then runs out of memory on XML component. And now twig shouts about zend_mm_heap corruption

Comment: @Misiur you can change the amount of memory available to PHP in the INI file.  I am running the 32 bit version with 1536 Mb as I have some large command line data processing scripts.  Running the tests is a good start, as it appears that things are working then.  What are the errors you are getting?  My Windows environment runs fine.

Comment: @Steven I've increased memory to 2G, but without change. Phpunit on phpunit gets stuck on some test (first 1055 run smoothly, then single test takes 1 hour (!)). Twig test on the other hand gives too much output (I thought that phpunit should output only dots, F and E's). Tap file of phpunit - http://pastebin.com/j6aFeY6V - last 3 tests were 1h long each and I aborted. Excerpt from windows console log for twig phpunit (740kb full file) - http://pastebin.com/E3ecAVPu . Thanks for your help

Comment: @Misiur I was unable to use 2GB, as I had errors in the 5.3.x branch when trying to execute. However, that should not matter here.  I believe you have the memory and now you are getting different errors.  Can you post the new, actual errors you are getting and maybe even a very simple example?